# Get index of parent based on child in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently the code below returns an array of visible parent/sibling div's with the class `.one-third`, but I need to find the position of the clicked article based on the returned array. For example, post-1320 would have an index of 0, post-1321 would return 1, post-1324 would return 2 etc.

Adding `.index('.'+unqiuePostClass[1])` to the end of the code returns -1 because it can't locate the class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1320">post-1320</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1321">post-1321</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third" style="display:none;">
    <article class="post post-1322">post-1322</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third" style="display:none;">
    <article class="post post-1323">post-1323</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1324">post-1324</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1325">post-1325</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1326">post-1326</article>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('.post').click(function() {
    var str = $(this).attr('class');
    var unqiuePostClass = str.split(" "); // unqiuePostClass[1] returns post-xxxx
    var result = $('.'+unqiuePostClass[1]).parent().siblings('.one-third:visible').addBack();

    console.log(result);

});
```

**RESULT**

```
0: div.one-third
1: div.one-third
2: div.one-third
3: div.one-third
4: div.one-third
```

A JSFiddle which better demonstrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/lustre/rtf5L0gv/5/

Comment: If you click on an article with class `.post` you determine the _unique_ post class of the clicked article and then you select all articles with this _unique_ class - which yields exactly the clicked article. Why the detour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) and pass in the selector of the elements it's relative to:

```
$(this).parent().index('div.one-third:visible')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rtf5L0gv/6/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.index()` on the `:visible` elements with class of `.one-third`

```js
$('.post').click(function() {
 var index = $('.one-third:visible > .post').index(this);
 console.log(index);
});
```

```css
.one-third {
    width:33.3333333333333%;
    float:left;
}

.post {
    background:red;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.clear {clear:both;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1320">post-1320</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1321">post-1321</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third" style="display:none;">
    <article class="post post-1322">post-1322</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third" style="display:none;">
    <article class="post post-1323">post-1323</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1324">post-1324</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1325">post-1325</article>
</div>
<div class="one-third">
    <article class="post post-1326">post-1326</article>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
```