# Get index of parent div based on child action

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```js
var $thumbs = $('.thumbs');

$thumbs.on('click', 'a', function($e) {
  $e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);

  console.log($this.parent().index('.thumbs'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col xs4 s12 m4 push-m8 thumbs">
   <div class="col xs4 s6">
       <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
       <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
       <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
       <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  
    <div class="col xs4 s6">
        <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="col xs4 s12 m4 push-m8 thumbs">
     <div class="col xs4 s6">
        <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col xs4 s6">
         <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
         <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
         <a href=""><img src="img_url.jpg"></a>
       </div>
</div>
```

All I want to know is what is the index of `thumbs` when a `a` element is clicked. So when `a` is clicked from the first `thumbs` I would expect the return to be `0` and from the second `thumbs` to be `1`. However for some reason I'm only getting `-1` returned.

Here are some more jQuery examples I've already tried () but without success:

- [Get index of parent based on child in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33107364/get-index-of-parent-based-on-child-in-jquery)
- [jQuery: Get index of element as child relative to parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996002/jquery-get-index-of-element-as-child-relative-to-parent)
- [Get index of clicked element in collection with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545283/get-index-of-clicked-element-in-collection-with-jquery)

Comment: Can you add data-index="xx" attribute to each element?

Comment: @MaxZoom I would prefer not to

Comment: Did you try [`.index(this)`](https://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element)?

Comment: @dsh Yes I have tried that but that failed aswell but the question already has an answer that works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `.thumbs` element is not the `parent` of the `a` element that was clicked. You need to traverse up the tree of elements.

You *could* do this with `.parent().parent()`, but that isn't very robust. Use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) instead:

```
console.log($this.closest('.thumbs').index('.thumbs'));
```